# Can we directly write Binaries to S3 using C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, binary, ceph

Can we directly write bytes to S3[File.dat] using C#. I have a requirement to write binary data to a file continuously in S3 storage system. I am able to copy a file from my local system to S3. But i am not able to write directly in to S3.
Can any one help me on this approach? Someone is saying that by using multi-part upload. But they transferring the large files, based on length.

```
  private const string AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "Access Key";
  private const string AWS_SECRET_KEY = "Security Key";

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AmazonS3Config s3config = new AmazonS3Config();
        s3config.ServiceURL = "https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/";

        AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, s3config);
        CreateFilesInBucket(client);
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\Documents\Test Folder\Test2.csv";
        UploadChunk(client,filepath); //Edited
    }

  private static void CreateFilesInBucket(AmazonS3Client client)
    {            
        Byte[] DatFile = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Documents\Test Folder\File.DAT");
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();          
        request.BucketName = "TestBucket";           
        request.ContentType = "binary";
        request.FilePath = @"C:\Users\Documents\Test Folder\File.DAT";
        client.PutObject(request);            
    }
```

**Edited:**
I am trying with the below code but it is throwing an error.

```
 public void UploadChunk(AmazonS3Client client, string filepath)
    {
        List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
        List<PartETag> lsttags = new List<PartETag>();
        // 1. Initialize.
        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = "TestBucket",
            Key = "Test4.dat"
        };

        InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
            client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);

        // 2. Upload Parts.
        long contentLength = new FileInfo(filepath).Length;
        long partSize = 5242880; // 5 MB
        long sizechk = 5242880;
        try
        {
            MemoryStream chnkmemry;
            byte[] bteary = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

            long filePosition = 0;
            long length = 0;
            for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++)
            {
                chnkmemry = new MemoryStream();
                partSize = Math.Min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));
                  if (partSize < sizechk ) break;
                chnkmemry.Write(bteary, (int)length, (int)partSize);


                length += chnkmemry.Length;
                // Create request to upload a part.
                UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "TestBucket",
                    Key = "Test4.dat",
                    UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                    PartNumber = i,
                    PartSize = partSize,
                    FilePosition = filePosition,
                    InputStream = chnkmemry
                };

                // Upload part and add response to our list.
                uploadResponses.Add(client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));
                lsttags.Add(new PartETag(i, uploadResponses[i-1].ETag));  
                filePosition += partSize;
            }

            // Step 3: complete.
            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = "TestBucket",
                Key = "Test4.dat",
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                PartETags = lsttags
            };

            CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
              client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception occurred: "+ exception.Message);
            AbortMultipartUploadRequest abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = "TestBucket",
                Key = "Test4.dat",
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
            };
            client.AbortMultipartUpload(abortMPURequest);
        }
    }
```

**Error making request with Error Code EntityTooSmall and Http Status Code BadRequest. No further error information was returned by the service.**

Thanks in advance.